# How do I host two servers on NGINX? (Django and Angular PWA)

Tags: django, angular, ubuntu, nginx

I want Django to keep all of its defined routes and Angular to be hosted from ip/pwa.

I have these block bodies:

```
#Angular
server {
  listen 123.456.7.89:80;
  root /home/pwa/dist/reportpwa;
  location /pwa {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}

#Django Database
server {
    listen 123.456.7.89:80;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/django-apps/reportdbapi;
    }
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

The servers seem to run fine on their own but when I put them both up together, the Django server takes over and refuses to recognize the Angular server. Can anyone tell me what kind of configuration I need to make them both work?

Comment: use diffrent ports

Comment: so I changed the port on my django backend to 81 in NGINX but its timing out now. any ideas sir?

Comment: thanks for the help dude. that will probably help.

Comment: got it working dude. silly me forgot to unblock the ports.